# Realizar contagem de dados com base no agrupamento de 2 ou mais colunas em um Pandas.DataFrame

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

Quero encontrar nesse DataFrame, os 3 melhores `user_id` por `Nome prova`. Ou seja, aqueles que possuem o maior número de valores 1 na coluna correta ( tal coluna é composta por valores `0` e `1` ):

```
                 Nome prova  user_id  correta
3      SABESP ASSESMENT RO       85        1
4      SABESP ASSESMENT RO       62        1
5      SABESP ASSESMENT RO       45        1
6      SABESP ASSESMENT RO       39        1
7      SABESP ASSESMENT RO       62        1
                   ...      ...      ...
24269       SICREDI UNID 7     1684        1
24271       SICREDI UNID 7     1695        1
24273       SICREDI UNID 7     1674        1
24275       SICREDI UNID 7     1681        1
24276       SICREDI UNID 7     1672        1
```

Eu tentei fazer da seguinte forma :

```
only_corrects = dataset[dataset.correta == 1]
best_participants = only_corrects[['Nome prova', 'user_id', 'correta']].groupby(['Nome prova', 'user_id']).sum()
best_participants.pivot_table(values='correta', index='user_id', columns='Nome prova')
```

porém oque recebo são vários valores `NaN` entre aqueles `user_id` que não realizaram a prova:

```
Nome prova  Provas Sabesp - RB  SABESP ASSESMENT RO  SICREDI UNID 7  Sabesp  \
user_id                                                                       
1                          NaN                  NaN             NaN     NaN   
2                          NaN                  NaN             NaN     NaN   
33                         NaN                  4.0             NaN     9.0   
34                         NaN                 11.0             NaN     NaN   
35                         NaN                  6.0             NaN     NaN   
                       ...                  ...             ...     ...   
1699                       NaN                  NaN             8.0     NaN   
1700                       NaN                  NaN             9.0     NaN   
1702                       NaN                  NaN            13.0     NaN   
1703                       NaN                  NaN             7.0     NaN   
1704                       NaN                  NaN            11.0     NaN
```

Tentei também apenas ultilizar o `groupby`:

```
only_corrects = dataset[dataset.correta == 1]
best_participants = only_corrects[['Nome prova', 'user_id', 'correta']].groupby(['Nome prova', 'user_id']).sum()
```

mas também sem sucesso:

```
                               correta
Nome prova         user_id         
Disal              404           10
                   405            5
                   406           11
                   407            9
                   408            6
                            ...
prova alto uruguai 785            8
                   786           11
                   787            5
                   788           11
                   789            7
```

Comment: Poderia anexar a pergunta um [mcve] mostrando a sua tentativa em resolver o problema, a mensagem de erro gerada e destacar a linha em que foi gerado o erro.

Comment: Eu tentei ultilizar a função groupby e a pivot_table pra realizar a soma e separação por user_id, mas ambas não retornam o resultado esperado

Comment: @AugustoVasques poderia por favor abrir à respostas a minha pergunta ? Não vejo onde ela poderia se diferenciar de quaisquer outras da mesma categoria e que receberam respostas.

Comment: Já dei o meu voto para reabrir, faltam os outros usuários.

Comment: Gostaria de lhe avisar que citei [sua pergunta no META](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/8295/campanha-postar-coment%c3%a1rios-ao-dar-votos-negativos-ou-de-fechamento-ven%c3%a7a-o-de#comment32734_8295) para não passar a impressão de estar falando de você pelas cóstas.

Comment: São necessários votos de 5 usuários experientes para reabrir. Acabei de dar o quarto voto.

Answer (score 1):

Mano, veja se é isso que você precisa

```
#Instalar pacote
#pip install pandas
#pip install numpy
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

lista_valores = [
['SABESP ASSESMENT RO',85,1]
,['SABESP ASSESMENT RO',62,1]
,['SABESP ASSESMENT RO',45,1]
,['SABESP ASSESMENT RO',39,1]
,['SABESP ASSESMENT RO',39,1]
,['SABESP ASSESMENT RO',62,1]
,['SABESP ASSESMENT RO',62,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1684,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1684,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1684,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1684,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1695,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1674,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1681,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1681,1]
,['SICREDI UNID 7',1672,1]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(lista_valores, columns = ['Nome Prova', 'user_id','correta'])

#Filtra os dados
aux = df[df.correta == 1]

#Agrupa as infomações
aux2 = aux.groupby((['Nome Prova','user_id']), as_index=False)['correta'].sum()

#Cria um ranking dos valores correta por Nome Prova
aux2["rank"] = aux2.groupby(['Nome Prova'])["correta"].rank("dense", ascending=False)

#Ordena os dados
aux2 = aux2.sort_values('rank', ascending=True)

#Salva os valores na lista
lista_final = []
[(lista_final.append(aux2[aux2['Nome Prova'] == x].head(3).values)) for x in aux2['Nome Prova'].unique()]

#Dataframe final
df = pd.DataFrame(np.concatenate(lista_final), columns = ['Nome Prova', 'user_id','correta','rank'])

#Deletar a coluna rank
del df['rank']

print(df)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]